# Поиск только по первому столбцу таблицы на Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать поиск по таблице, но только по первому и второму столбцах. Есть пример взятый отсюда https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html который мне отлично подходит.

```
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
 
    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;
 
                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
    });
 
} );
</script>
```

Но там получается что под каждой колонкой появляется поле для поиска. А мне нужно только чтобы под первой и второй было это поле. Может можно как то каждому

присвоить свой класс и потом я бы в стилях (CSS) ненужные отключил? Или может еще какие-нибудь другие варианты есть?

Comment: Из Ваших одиннадцати вопросов Вам ответили на восемь. Вас что, ни один ответ не устроил?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете поставить ограничение через js на появление данного поля. 
Например, по ключу массива объектов 0 и 1.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example tfoot th').each( function (k) {
            if(k===0 || k===1){ // Если только первый и второй столбец
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
            }
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            initComplete: function () {
                // Apply the search
                this.api().columns().every( function () {
                    var that = this;

                    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                            that
                                .search( this.value )
                                .draw();
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            }
        });

    } );
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2011/04/25</td>
    <td>$320,800</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>2011/07/25</td>
    <td>$170,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>2009/01/12</td>
    <td>$86,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>2012/03/29</td>
    <td>$433,060</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>2011/06/27</td>
    <td>$183,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Donna Snider</td>
    <td>Customer Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>$112,000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```